# How can I load webview content by pressing a button in expo?do I have to use navigation?

Tags: android, react-native, button, webview, expo

How can I load  webview content by  pressing a button in expo?do I have to use navigation?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import {View} from 'react-native'
export default function App(){
    return (
      <View>
      <Button title={'CLICK'} onPress={()=> <WebView source={{uri:'https://www.google.com'}}/>}>
      </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a concept called "states". They are well explained in the official documentation of React. Basically you have to declare a changeable variable and then change it with the button. When a state change detected, React re-renders the corresponding components. And when it is re-rendered, new value of that particular variable is read and according changes happen.  Here is a code snippet that serves your desired purpose:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { View, Button } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <View
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
    >
        // on press, whatever the older value of isVisible was, set it to its opposite, eg. toggle it 
        <Button
            title="click"
            onPress={() => setIsVisible((prev) => !prev)}
            color="blue"
        />
        // if isVisible is true, render the WebView
        {isVisible && (
            // you probably will want to change WebView's styles
            <WebView
                style={{ width: 300, height: 250 }}
                source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com" }}
            />
        )}
    </View>
);
}
```